# find the degree of the field extension $\mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt{3} , \omega )$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: galois-theory

let $\omega$  be  a primitive  complex cube  root  of unity  and $i =\sqrt {-1}$.find the  degree  of the  field   extension  $\mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt{3} , \omega )$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

**My attempt** :   $[\mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt{3} , \omega ):\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt{3} , \omega ):\mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{3} , \omega )][\mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{3} , \omega ):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})][\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}):\mathbb{Q}]=2.2.2=8$

Is my answer correct   ?

Comment: No, your answer is not correct. The first equation is correct, but it turns out that one of those three extension degrees is actually equal to one. Can you tell which? Hint: Write $\omega$ in terms of square roots. It is a root of 
$$\omega^2+\omega+1=0.$$ Write down the roots using the quadratic formula.

Comment: okay you mean  to say  that $1/2 \in \mathbb{Q}$ and  $\sqrt{3} i/2 \in\mathbb{Q} (i,\sqrt {3})$ @JyrkiLahtonen sir

Comment: Correct. Either $\omega\in \Bbb{Q}(i,\sqrt3)$ or $i\in\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt3,\omega)$. Whichever way you want to look at it.